# Input masking with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to do input masking with react:

This is what I have so far. I can't seem to get the value to update correctly, I also want the cursor to be at the beginning when they click in the input. I am kind of stuck from here.

Expected output from input : something like `0_ / _ _` => `0 9 / 0 _` => `0 9 / 0 9`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    };

    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }
  update(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formatString = '_ _ / _ _';
    const newString = `${e.target.value}${formatString.slice(
      e.target.value.length
    )}}`;
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: newString });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.update}
          name="inputValue"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onFocus={() => this.setState({ inputValue: '_ _ / _ _' })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So  whenever user types something it will be replaced in this string '_ _ / _ _ ' right ?

Comment: Yes so something like `0_ / _ _` , `0 9 / 0 _ `, `0 9 / 0 9`, ill add this in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onChange` event will be called each time you type a new character in the input box. So you will only need the last character for that string. That is done as followed.

`const lastChar = e.target.value[e.target.value.length - 1];`

Now you need to replace this at a particulate position in your formatted string. To keep track of the position, I am using `count` state variable. Updating the count variable is a very simple logic and specific to the input string (Position 0,2,6,8 needs to be replaced in the same order). Finally, you will replace that specific position with the last character you just extracted.

`const newString = prevString.substr(0, count) + lastChar + prevString.substr(count + 1);`

Here is the working example. https://codesandbox.io/s/432608n5w7

Comment: Awesome, I just have one question, is there a way to move the cursor the front when the user clicks the box and have the cursor move with each number input? This is still a great answer though.

Comment: I am looking for this. Will let you know and update the answer if I find something.